# Non-inductive proof for diagonalizing commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A_1,\dots, A_k$ are $n\times n$ unitary matrices such that any two of them commute. Does anybody know a non-inductive proof that all of them can be diagonalized simultaneously?